# Best practice for AVRCP on Android (sending meta-data to bluetooth device)

Tags: android, bluetooth, avrcp

I want to send meta-data to a bluetooth device, via an Android 4.3+ device.

The solution that I came across, and that works, is sending an intent to google.android.music (the google music app), informing it about the meta-data, as seen here: [send track informations via A2DP/AVRCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527614/send-track-informations-via-a2dp-avrcp). I might be wrong, but this does not seem to be the way AVRCP should work on android.

As far as I understood, the best practice would be to use [RemoteControlClient.MetadaDataEditor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.html) like so:

```
        mRemoteControlClient.editMetadata(true)
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, playingItem.getArtist())
```

This is actually advised by google themselves as the best practice: http://youtu.be/EC5-cEbr520?t=25m18s

The problem is that I cannot make my app to send meta-data to the bluetooth device with the advised RemoteControlClient.MetadaDataEditor class, but using the intent to the google music app it works.

Does anybody know why this happens? What is the most correct way to send meta-data to the bluetooth device? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? Looking to do something very similar.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33221137/3944092) for sending metadata via A2DP/AVRCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST instead.