# Show Title (not song or artist but active SIP conversation) on Bluetooth CarKit from Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, sip, phone-call, headset

So I'm currently developing a SIP dial app and I was wondering how I could change the displayed information on a Bluetooth CarKit. I route the audio to the carkit using :

```
    AudioManager localAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    localAudioManager.setMode(0);
    localAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
    localAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
    localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

And I am wondering: How am I able to set the caller info on the bluetooth device? I wasn't able to find this anywhere on SO. To be extra clear this is what I see during an active conversation:

[image: call]

I also use a library for SIP conversations called **PortSIP**. Maybe they have influence on what to display? I don't know. Any ideas are welcome. I've already tried searching on options for **AudioManager**, the only option I can imagine that leaves room for metadata is **audioManager.setParameters()**, but I can't find what the possible key value parameters are for this function.

Update: Also tried to show info like trackinfo, but still didn't succeed. This is the code I've tried:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.music.metachanged");
    intent.putExtra("track", "test");
    intent.putExtra("artist", "atest");
    intent.putExtra("album", "btest");
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this question + answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246028/best-practice-for-avrcp-on-android-sending-meta-data-to-bluetooth-device

Comment: Plus this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527614/send-track-informations-via-a2dp-avrcp

Comment: Checked them as described in post, but they seem to be MediaPlayer exclusive. Will also check with controls, found a post that metachanged has no effect without controls.

Answer (score 2):

I found a post that explanes how to send metadata information from your phone to a connected audio bluetooth device.

If you just want to send metadata information from your phone to a connected AVRCP compatible audio bluetooth device and DON'T want to control your app from the bluetooth device at all, check the post below.

[This is the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33221137/2917564)