# How do I make shuffle playlist button and repeat button in android studio

Tags: android, button, android-studio, repeat, shuffle

I dont know how to convert this code to android studio i am stuck on it for 2 days and cant figure it out Plz help me

btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isRepeat){
                isRepeat = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }else{
                // make repeat to true
                isRepeat = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isShuffle = false;
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }
        }
    });
```

and another one

btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isShuffle){
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }else{
                // make repeat to true
                isShuffle= true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isRepeat = false;
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }
        }
    });
```

this is last pice of code

@Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

```
    // check for repeat is ON or OFF
    if(isRepeat){
        // repeat is on play same song again
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else if(isShuffle){
        // shuffle is on - play a random song
        Random rand = new Random();
        currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else{
        // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
        if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        }else{
            // play first song
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like a toggle button! Instead of a normal button so you don't have to care what is switched on and off! Here the JavaDoc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

And this link contains a nice tutorial on how to use it within your code:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-togglebutton-example/