# i cant send metadata from A2DP mobile device but Google Play Music send metadata to that device how?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, metadata, a2dp

I have a bluetooth devices which support **A2DP\AVRCP** but my mobile dosen't support AVRCP so i cant send metadata but Google Play Music sends metadata to that device how?

**Tested Physical Device :** Google Pixel XL,Samsung Galaxy Amp Prime.

Wile testing i got logs of Google Play Music which run this service `bta2dp_codec_info_callback` need more detail on that....

I already tried the code snippet mentioned in the link

**Reference :** [send track informations via A2DP/AVRCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527614/send-track-informations-via-a2dp-avrcp)

```
7.0 My App Logging 

019-04-22 10:03:53.773 6918-16996/com.xyz I/ACodec:  [] Now uninitialized
2019-04-22 10:03:53.779 6918-17042/com.xyz I/ACodec: [] onAllocateComponent
2019-04-22 10:03:53.791 6918-17042/com.xyz I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
2019-04-22 10:03:53.834 6918-17042/com.xyz I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Loaded
2019-04-22 10:03:53.843 6918-17042/com.xyz I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Loaded->Idle
2019-04-22 10:03:53.856 6918-17042/com.xyz I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Idle->Executing
2019-04-22 10:03:53.858 6918-17042/com.xyz I/ACodec: [OMX.SEC.mp3.dec] Now Executing

7.0 Google App Logging:

2019-04-22 10:08:41.965 8850-8880/? D/bt_btif_media_if: Codec ==> capability info:60 [btif_a2dp_setup_codec:line1318]
2019-04-22 10:08:42.006 8850-8880/? I/BluetoothA2dpServiceJni: bta2dp_codec_info_callback, 0
2019-04-22 10:08:42.006 8850-8880/? D/A2dpStateMachine: onCodecInfoUpdateCallback pSupportedCodecs:0
2019-04-22 10:09:38.033 8850-8880/? D/bt_btif_media_if: Codec ==> capability info:60 [btif_a2dp_setup_codec:line1318]
2019-04-22 10:09:38.063 8850-8880/? I/BluetoothA2dpServiceJni: bta2dp_codec_info_callback, 0
2019-04-22 10:09:38.063 8850-8880/? D/A2dpStateMachine: onCodecInfoUpdateCallback pSupportedCodecs:0
```

Comment: see [A2dpNativeInterface.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/bluetooth/a2dp/A2dpNativeInterface.java)... while it reads `onCodecInfoUpdateCallback pSupportedCodecs:0`.

Comment: https://github.com/illiacdev/Bluetooth-A2DP/ 
i am using this repo to play song how can i use A2dpNativeInterface.java file in this project 
please give more detail on implementation. @MartinZeitler